# reverse the JSON Array stored in javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a json array stored in variable in format below:

```
{"info": 
[ {"typeid": "877", "recid": "10", "repeaterid": "0",  "pageid": "26966", "maxrecords": "1"},
  {"typeid": "877", "recid": "11", "repeaterid": "0",  "pageid": "26966", "maxrecords": "1"},
  {"typeid": "459", "recid": "3", "repeaterid": "0",  "pageid": "26966", "maxrecords": "1"},
  {"typeid": "459", "recid": "4", "repeaterid": "0",  "pageid": "26966", "maxrecords": "1"},
  {"typeid": "456", "recid": "5", "repeaterid": "0",  "pageid": "26966", "maxrecords": "1"},
  {"typeid": "456", "recid": "6", "repeaterid": "0",  "pageid": "26966", "maxrecords": "1"}
]}
```

I want to reverse the inner JSON array for info.Like this

```
{"info": 
[ {"typeid": "456", "recid": "6", "repeaterid": "0",  "pageid": "26966", "maxrecords": "1"},
  {"typeid": "456", "recid": "5", "repeaterid": "0",  "pageid": "26966", "maxrecords": "1"},
  {"typeid": "459", "recid": "4", "repeaterid": "0",  "pageid": "26966", "maxrecords": "1"},
  {"typeid": "459", "recid": "3", "repeaterid": "0",  "pageid": "26966", "maxrecords": "1"},
  {"typeid": "877", "recid": "11", "repeaterid": "0",  "pageid": "26966", "maxrecords": "1"},
  {"typeid": "877", "recid": "10", "repeaterid": "0",  "pageid": "26966", "maxrecords": "1"}
]}
```

How can i achieve this.

[image]

Comment: Would you like to sort the array or just reverse it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the array [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) method of Javascript:

```
var objAssetSelection = $.parseJSON(strAssetSelection);
objAssetSelection.info.reverse();
console.log(objAssetSelection);
```

Comment: getting undefined for info.

Comment: Did you replace `var` with the actual name of your variable that contains the object?

Comment: Ahh, you haven't parsed the JSON into an object yet.

Comment: My bad.....Thanks barmar. That was very helpful. one last question is it possible to reverse the array as well as sort them on the basis of pageid??

Comment: You can do whatever you want with the array. Javascript has a `sort` function, ojovirtual's answer shows how to use it.

Comment: and how can i convert back to string array from json array objAssetSelection??

Comment: With `JSON.stringify`.

Answer (score 6):

Did you tried `myObject.info.reverse()` ?

More about [Javascript Array Reverse](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reverse.asp)

Comment: getting undefined for info.

Answer (score 2):

```
var sorted=yourobject.info.sort(function(a,b){return a.typeid-b.typeid});
```

Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Answer (score 2):

and simply (JQuery needed) :

```
function test() {
    var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    var myReversedArray = new Array();
    $(myArray).each(function (key) {
        myReversedArray.unshift(myArray[key]);
    });
    myArray = myReversedArray;
    $(myArray).each(function (key) {
        console.log(myArray[key]);
    });
}
```

Comment: Note my solution is not the quickest but I think it's the simpliest.
I compared mine to all of those : 
http://jsperf.com/js-array-reverse-vs-while-loop/20
Result was : 53,390,542±1.33%85% slower

Answer (score 0):

Successfully Working Converting JSON Array to Reverse JSON Array 101% Working

```
var ActualArray = [{
        "bag":'large',
        "color":'blue'
    },{
        "bag":'small',
        "color":'red'
    },{
        "bag":'medium',
        "color":'green'
    },{
        "bag":'large',
        "color":'pink'
    }]
    var ReverseArray = [];
    var length = ActualArray.length;
    for(var i = length-1;i>=0;i--){
        ReverseArray.push(ActualArray[i]);
    }
    console.log("actual array");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(ActualArray));
    console.log("reverse array");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(ReverseArray));
```

Your Log will be like below

```
actual array
[{"bag":"large","color":"blue"},{"bag":"small","color":"red"},{"bag":"medium","color":"green"},{"bag":"large","color":"pink"}]
reverse array
[{"bag":"large","color":"pink"},{"bag":"medium","color":"green"},{"bag":"small","color":"red"},{"bag":"large","color":"blue"}]
```